# AccessController Applets Issue

Tags: java, security, applet, access-control

I have an applet and start some process on Windows from applet. *When I start this process just from another code(test), this code works fine and process runs from rt.exec() to proc.destroy().* **When I use html call for applet - process runs only for 5 seconds every time (!!!) and then just alive, but doesn't work, to proc.destroy().** This is really interesting for me (newbie in applets). I think, this issue caused by AccessController. Help me please to solve this (run process normally for longer than 5 seconds) ! Thanks in advance.

P.S. I use Windows, medium Java security lever and applet is self-signed. It asks me to 'allow', applet works.

Here's the code:

```
    public String startRecording(final String filename) throws IOException {
    try {
        return (String) AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {
                    public String run() {
                        try {
                            proc = Runtime
                                    .getRuntime()
                                    .exec(cmd + filename + "." + config.getFormat());
                            //proc.waitFor();
                            return "Ffmpeg process started";
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            return e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

And stop method here

```
public void stopRecording() {
    proc.destroy();
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
It's FFMPEG process, which records desktop video and writes it to file, maybe AccessController blocks access to file system.

Comment: Given that `filename` could be anything malicious, that doesn't look very safe. / Is this stopping five seconds after LiveConnect and applet activity finished? Sounds like it's the PlugIn clearing up runaway processes. So keep the applet running (and pin down the filename).

Comment: I understood about filename. I dont really know is applet running, how to check it? Process is alive, but doesnt work.

Comment: If I start process via Windows Command Prompt, my process keeps alive and running. THIS IS CRAZY, help me !

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the I/O streams. Just redirect error(in case of ffmpeg) stream to file. This solves problem (but dont know why :) ).